# Specifying fonts in xterm

Tags: x11, fonts, xterm

I'm having difficulty gettings fonts to display correctly in `xterm`.  The situation is complicated by this being a headless server which I'm connecting to from a Macbook Pro via `xpra`, with no desktop environment installed on the server.

It does appear that `~/.Xresources` is being read.  But if the contents are simply

```
XTerm*renderFont: true
XTerm*faceName: mono:normal:size=9
```

then the font used is italicized and seemingly bold.

What are the minimal contents I need in the `Xresources` file to get a non-italicized, monospace font?

Some related questions:

- I always (or almost always) get this warning:  `Cannot convert string "nil2" to type FontStruct`
- In any given xterm, how do I list the font it's actually using?  I've found solutions on the web for listing the default font that will be used (e.g. `appres`), but not for the one actually being used in this particular instance.

Comment: You might try `fc-match mono:normal:size=9`

Answer (score 3):

The [xterm manual](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html) shows an option which may help (added in [patch #298](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_298) in 2013):

> [**`-report-fonts`**](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-report-fonts)
>                  Print a report to the standard output showing information about
>                  fonts which are loaded.  This corresponds  to  the  [**`reportFonts`**](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Application-Resources:reportFonts)
>                  resource.

Also, `appres` is useful for showing what resources are used, e.g.,

```
*VT100.font3:   6x10
*VT100.font4:   7x13
*VT100.font5:   9x15
*VT100.font6:   10x20
*VT100.font1:   nil2
*VT100.font2:   5x7
```

When `xterm` cannot allocate a font, it tries to use `fixed`.